# Scientists do not know why speed of light is the same for all observers?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics, causality

It has taken me sometime to even understand what this speed of light is all about.
I have simply heard that the speed of light is constant in all inertial or in all reference frames without really knowing actually what it means.

After a long time I came to realize that it is not like you put a car on cruise control and the car moves nicely maintaining the same speed.   I suddenly became aware, oh no.  What the scientists are saying is totally something else.  That the speed of light whether you are moving in the same direction as light and no matter how fast you are moving. or you are moving opposite to it or you are standing still, it will make no difference.  The light will pass everybody exactly at the same speed, no matter which person is measuring it.

It dawned on me that this is surely not about speed at all.  It can not be.  Absolutely not.
The math does not add up.

Then I began to look carefully if there is answer or what the answer for it is, in science.
I found none.
Then I realized that, this was also Einstein's struggle and that is what it is all about.   It forced Einstein to come up with his theory of relativity which was also over anybody's head.  Time and Space can not be written in stone and must be flexible entities.

And left the speed of light alone and so found a way to explain why it is measured that way by everyone.
However, it is clear without really catching the fact that time dilation and space contraction is a consquence of the speed and not the cause of it.

It took me a bit to see that detail.

To discuss this and to actually reveal this to the science academic experts have got me nowhere.  I am not even sure if they understand me or know what the issue actually is.

Now the question is left here to be tackled with since I have basically either got kicked out of science forums or at best left empty handed.

What is the cause of this stange anomoly?

Light will pass you by at 186,000 miles per second no matter how fast you will go.  So why even try. Might as well not waste gas.

Are you going to leave me empty handed?
You are my last resort and whatever you do, don't kick me out.  In other words don't view my question is meaningless and makes no sense or that my grammer and spelling is bad.

If there are misspellings, missing vowels feel free to correct it.

Comment: The math does add up, literally, it just is a different math, see [velocity-addition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula). And once you think of it you realize that that no more "cause" is needed for it to be this way than the classical way we are more used to. Why not? Why *shouldn't* it be the relativistic addition instead of classical addition? Something is not an anomaly in need of explanation just because it happens to startle us. And what difference does it make how fast the light passes us if the gas still gets us from point A to point B?

Comment: The idea that the speed of light is the same for all inertial frames depends on the idea that each frame uses rulers and clocks at rest in that frame to measure the distance and time between events (and that each frame sees rulers in other frames as shortened and clocks in other frames running slow), and that each frame synchronizes their own clocks using the [Einstein synchronization convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation), which implies that they [disagree about which pairs of events are "simultaneous"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity).

Comment: (cont.) My answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/142330/59406) gives a numerical example showing how, when you take into account length contraction, time dilation, and the relativity of simultaneity, the math does work out that light is traveling at the same speed in two different frames, as measured by their own rulers and clocks. Also see my illustrated example [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/155016/59406) showing how each frame symmetrically measures the other one's rulers to be shrunk and the other one's clocks to be slow and out-of-synch.

Comment: Hypnosifl, The only way you know that the other ruler and clock have contracted  or is different is when that  information becomes available which puts you back simply in another frame. That is all.  You would never know anything about the other frame of refrence at all unless another frame of reference puts the two together.  Consider the fact that it is impossible to measure the speed of light one way.  This is reflected in Einstein's " Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies".  Relativity forbids it.  I am not sure if folks really sees the extent of this.  So what is really going on?

Comment: Scientists have known why the speed of light is constant for more than 150 years. See this [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light), at the "propagation of light" chapter. Light is an electromagnetic wave, the electric field induces a magnetic one, which in turn induces an electric one and so on. Therefore the speed of propagation is determined only by how fast each field can induce the other, and both constants are independent of any observer or their frame of reference. Of course that raised lots of questions, but the validity of Maxwell's work is not disputed.

Comment: Don't mind me if I said this: Everything I have read here and below is easily found online and more, much more.  No new finds and worse yet I am afraid I never made my point.  I should have never started my post with anything that had anything to do or related to speed of light or anything that would have even reminded someone in that line of trajectory.  It is too late now. I burned this.  Maybe someone might come along and see it for what it is.  It is all good.  Chances are I would make it another day, wake up and see the Sun rise.   Well, thank you all for now.

Comment: Read Einstein directly:  " Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies".   Einstein considered constancy of speed of light as a postulate that can not be explained.   I just didn't realize that most people knows more than Einstein.  My bad.   Heisenburg on his deathbed was struggling and could not understand it.   I guess they didn't live long enough to see how everyone has got it under control and knows it all.   Unfortunately I have not evolved to brightness or maybe my English is bad.  I just don't know.

Comment: I think you are confusing the constance of the speed of light and the postulate that nothing can go faster.

Comment: [Speed of Light May Not Be Constant, Physicists Say](https://www.livescience.com/29111-speed-of-light-not-constant.html)... maybe the things will change in the future. Science is "moving", new facts are discovered, new theories are developed to explain this facts and the already known ones. Every theory has postulates and some unexplained facts, as well as some assumptions not itself explained. That's life...

Comment: What is not clear to me in your post is this: are you concerned with the "internal consistency" of the theory of which the independence of the speed of light from the reference frame is part of? In this case, a textbook about Relativity Theory will explain it.

Comment: @Ali - "The only way you know that the other ruler and clock have contracted or is different is when that information becomes available which puts you back simply in another frame" What do you mean? You can directly measure the length of a ruler moving relative to you using *local* measurements on your own ruler/clock system--do you understand that all frames agree about localized events like what one clock reads at the moment another clock passes next to it? See the final diagram from [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/155016/59406) I linked to earlier for an example.

Comment: Hypnosifl, If you are seeing another clock going slower, it makes it your reference frame that is what I call when the information becomes available to you which is the speed of light.  The one with the clock sees yours to be moving slower.  That makes it his reference frame, he can not know it unless he recieves that information too. This clearly shows something that no one wants to touch.  We, us, ourselves are not outside the system looking in and observing as independent observers..... oh no, everybody wants to avoid that type of talk.  Not good.

Comment: [This answer on physics.se](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/658914/195139) provides some useful insight on the questions of why the laws of physics are a certain way.

Comment: Mauro, In a nutshell I am seeing this, cutting through the chase so to speak. Are we sure we are independent of the observation, that is you know looking in?  Is our science the science of the universe or the science of how we actually perceive it?  Our sense perception.  This is not a good way to talk.  It is what everyone wants to avoid.  And don't get me wrong, I do not mean solopsism. I want to make sure that is clear.

Comment: You my have a look at Einstein's Evolution of Physics ( at archive.org). You will see that the fact that " velocity of light is the same for all inertial frames" is taken as a postulate of the special theory of relativity. This postulate expresses an experimental fact ( a given) and , in this sense, the is no " why" question about it. (  You don't ask why a postulate is true, you take it for granted and derive the consequences). - Later formutaions of the theory managed to make this " fact" a consequence of the theory.

Comment: In my opinion, what you should care about is " how are the Lorentz transformations derived" https://oyc.yale.edu/sites/default/files/notes_relativity_3.pdf

Comment: The derivation of the Loretntz transformations shows that the speed of light as such is not as important as one may think. At a point of the derivation, a certain limiting speed apprears: this is the essential fact. After that, this limiting speed is expressed in terms of spped of light, in order to make the transformation match with the observed fact that " the speed of light" ( and of all electromagnetic waves" is the same in all inertial frames.

Comment: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00132616/document

Answer (score 2):

This article comes with great moving diageams to help explore and understand relativity: [Inside Einstein's head](https://www.lucify.com/inside-einsteins-head/)

Your intuition, everyone's until it was tested, was that there is a [luminiferous ether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether), a medium like a liquid, which events propagate through. There is not.

Light is not unaffected by what speed an observer is going - it can be red-shifted or blue-shifted, which changes it's energy, and which we can understand as a result of time dilation.

[Photons don't experience time](https://phys.org/news/2014-05-does-light-experience-time.html). It is notable that gravitational waves also travel at the speed of light. We should think of this as the fundamental limit for the propagation of events through space-time. Particles with rest mass interact with the Higgs field, making them propagate more slowly. The case of neutrinos is interesting, where their ability to oscillate between types [directly showed they must have mass](https://youtu.be/pIq654AMHEw).

Space and time are not the self-evident absolute things we think they are. They are sets of symmetries and relationships. Our intuitions have been shaped by physics at low energies, small speeds, and in relatively weak magnetic fields. We can't rely on intuition, we have to look at the world. The speed of light being the same in all rest frames is simply a brute fact, one that has interesting consequences. It is not the universe's concern what we feel comfortable with.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128579/discussion-on-answer-by-criglcragl-scientists-do-not-know-why-speed-of-light-is).

Answer (score 2):

Your question and comments seem to concern three distinct things.

1. Why do we believe that the speed of light is the same to all observers?
2. Why does the motion of things moving at high speeds not add in the simple way that it does at low speeds?
3. Why does nothing travel faster than the speed of light in a vacuum?

#1. You are correct to point out that Einstein treated the constancy of the speed of light to all observers as a *postulate*. We cannot demonstrate it directly, because we can only ever measure the round trip speed of light, so we cannot rule out that light travels faster in one direction than another. But arguably it is the simplest account of how light travels, and it also follows from the adoption of the Einstein synchronisation convention. You might object that simplicity is merely a pragmatic justification for accepting a postulate, and a convention is just a convention. But in science it is typical for theories to be underdetermined by data, so we often make use of pragmatic criteria for preferring one theory over another. Simplicity and symmetry are just such criteria.

#2. As to how motions combine at relativistic speeds: Galileo proposed that velocities combine simply by adding them as vectors. This works at low speeds, but it assumes in effect that light travels infinitely quickly. Even within classical physics, Galileo's version of the relativity of motion was known to be a problem, because it is inconsistent with Maxwell's equations. For velocities to combine in a way that is consistent with Maxwell's equations, they have to obey the Lorentz equations, not Galileo's. Einstein's theory of special relativity is one way of reconciling the Lorentz equations with the constancy of the laws of physics in all inertial frames.

#3. The constant that we call the speed of light in a vacuum is fundamentally not really a property of light at all, but a property of the universe. You can think of it as the speed limit of the universe, or the speed limit of causality. Light travels at this speed in a vacuum because light is massless, so it gets to travel at the speed limit. Other massless things like gluons and gravity waves also travel at this speed. There has to be a finite speed limit to the universe, because by the E=mc<sup>2</sup> relation, an amount of energy equal to mc<sup>2</sup> would be required for a mass m to exist. If c were infinite, then an infinite amount of energy would be required, so matter would not be able to exist. So, the fact that nothing travels faster than light in a vacuum is not because there is something special about light: it is just a limitation imposed by the universe.

Comment: Bumble;  "it is just a limitation imposed by the universe", the conclusion.  It is indeed what one finds when googling it or anywhere for that matter.  One is at last in the same shoes as Einstein, Heisenburg and the rest.   Space and time shall bend over backwards to make sure the speed of light consistently remains the same and to make sure Maxwell's equation is not violated.    Not good to make this look like some conspiracy if one wants to still get some respect.  :-).   A somewhat rational mind is tempted to conclude that something is missing.

Comment: And perhaps one should or could start with a statement like this but nobody does:  Our science is actually a science of what we actually experience and not the science of the universe independent of us as observers.  Every fiber of our body, all the firing of our nervous system, every pulse and every movement, all our experience and thought process is not outside the system looking in. All of it operate at the speed of causality, EM propagation.  That is we are not separate isolated observers looking in.   But saying that opens a big old can of worms that everyone avoids to get too close to.

Comment: The statement " speed limit of the universe" does not explain the bewildering, the real conundrum, how light behaves like the perfect strange get away car and the kind that makes no sense to a rational way of thinking at all.  Whether you stand still, or chase it or go at it in opposite direction, it speed stays exactly the same.  This can not be wiped over with that statement, i.e. speed limit of the universe and we know it.  It is not a type of speed like putting a car on steady cruise control.

Comment: @Ali, when we say that we know things in physics (like the constant speed of light), we do not mean that we looked at the source code of the universe and found the part that codes in the constancy of the speed of light. Rather, we mean that our theory of the constant speed of light and all of its predictions are consistent with observations. The universe independent of observers is also [inaccessible to observation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)).

Comment: Sandejo,  tell me the part of the universe that is independent ( inaccessable) of us as observers.  Before you answer it, look very closely at it so you know it is outside of you for sure.  And clearly see the line of separation.  You know, like here is Mexico and here is U.S. :-)

Comment: @Ali If you're looking at it, then that's just what you experience, not some universe independent of us ([if such a thing even exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-realism)). Also, if you want someone to be notified of your reply, put an @ before their name.

Comment: @Sandejo, thank you I have been meaning to ask that.   I think you are maybe seeing my point.  In your own statement.... lets pause it for a couple of seconds......"just what we experience".    Now we can go from there.  Without getting out of hand, lets approach it by the very science we have on hand.  .... For crying out why do we humans experience it that way.  Aha,  it is precisely the point of my post.  Einstein nor anyone lese dug in there.....  why?  Now are you going to dig there with me...  And keep it out of solopsism?.....  We are more clear than that.

Comment: @Ali *"why do we humans experience it that way"* Now, that's a very different question from what you started with. Personally, I'm not sure that it can be answered, but perhaps someone else here could offer more insight.

Comment: @Sandejo, take a look at my post, the question is clear:  "What is the cause of this stange anomoly?".  Lets not getting too picky.  It is in context of the behavior of light.   Why folks have a tendency not to get this is also part of the subject as far as I am concerned.  It is part of why the mind resists to go there and it shows.  They unconsciouly avoid the main point.  So here we are. So the question is, are you gonna go there.  You don't have to. Einstein didn't go there. None of them did. Nor does anyone here.

Comment: @Sandejo, I honestly feel you have the answer. I am only consciously optimistic.  You have nibbled at its toes.  It is rare that someone has gone this far with me.  You can go there with me.  I have the answer but I can't say it.  It doesn't work that way. It will have no meaning.  A real answer is never given.  A real answer is seen by the person for the person.

Comment: @Bumble, I have made comments up above in regard to your commentaries. I didn't know to place the symbol @ so the individual is notified.

Comment: @Ali The idea that light is a constant to all observers is indeed very puzzling to us, because it is completely different from how things behave at slow, non-relativistic speeds. But that is just the point: we are only familiar with how things behave at slow speeds. The Galilean mechanics that seems obvious because it is familiar turns out to be just a limiting case of Lorentz. The mechanics of fast-moving things is strange just because it is unfamiliar. If we lived in a world where the speed of light was very low, relativistic effects would be familiar and obvious.